# Why the amount of time between each block creation is not exact?

Tags: blockchain, crowdsale, tokens

I have seen that crowdsales are measured in blocks instead of time, but that there is an exact amount of blocks that represent a week or a month. If the time beetween blocks is not always the same, why a crowdsale developer can know kind of exactly how many blocks represent a month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Ethereum blockchain, the average time needed to mine a block is 15 seconds.
According to that, you can estimate how many blocks represent a month/day/hour/...

To check the past blocks mining time: https://etherscan.io/chart/blocktime

In Ethereum, time to mine a block should be 15 seconds. If this time appears to be too high for, lets say, block A, the next block (lets call it block B) will see its difficulty reduced in order to stay at around 15 seconds per block.
On the opposit, if mining time is too fast, difficulty will be increased.